# Как сделать такой эффект фона?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать такой же эффект, как на сайте ниже, при котором фон остаётся на месте, а сайт "листается" дальше?

http://ru.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1732?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fru.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fall%2F1&bookName=&galleryDocIndex=1&category=all

Comment: Такой эффект называется "Параллакс".

Answer (score 2):

```
.bg-box{
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("ваша картинка");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 480px;
}
```